# How do I prevent a menu item from appearing?

Tags: views, 6, routes, users

I have a View with a page display. I placed the path of that page view in a menu item. I placed this link under the menu path Primary Links > Apps > Home > Admin View.

In the View defaults section, I set two roles to be able to view the page: administrator and a custom admin role I created.

I have a user that does not have the administrator or the custom admin role. They can see the Home menu item, but they can also see the Admin View. If they click on Admin View, they receive the error "You are not authorized to access this page."

I thought that in Drupal 6 menu items do not appear unless the user has access to them. I have another View for Project Manager Admin, and my user does not see that menu item.

Does anyone have any suggestions regarding where to start debugging this problem? I would like for the Admin View menu item to not appear for my user because my user does not have access to it.

I have tried logging on as the user in question in a different browser and on a different machine, and I can still see the menu item.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the menu item in question, and then I re-created it.

I could see the menu item when logged on as my self.  I could NOT see the menu item when logged on as the user in question.

Deleting the menu item and re-creating it caused my issue to go away.